# Expectation of a transformed normal CDF

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

If we define a random variable $X \sim N(0,1)$ with $\Phi$ being the cdf of a standard normal, what would $E(\Phi(a+bX))$ be?

I was only able to rewrite $\Phi(a+bX)$ as $P(Z\leq aX+b|X)$ with $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

I could also calculate the cdf of $\Phi(a+bX)$ [as per this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392827/normal-random-variable-as-argument-of-standard-normal-cdf) but it doesn't help with its expectation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449875/expected-value-of-normal-cdf/1125935, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/how-can-i-calculate-int-infty-infty-phi-left-fracw-ab-right-phiw. The answer is $\Phi(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b\ne 0$,

\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}\Phi(a+bX)&=\int_0^{\infty}\mathsf{P}(\Phi(a+bX)>t)\,dt \\
&=\int_0^1\mathsf{P}(X>(\Phi^{-1}(t)-a)/b)\,dt \\
&=1-\int_0^1\Phi((\Phi^{-1}(t)-a)/b)\,dt.
\end{align}

When $a=0$ and $b=1$, the third line reduces to
$$
1-\int_0^1 t\,dt=\frac{1}{2}.
$$